# C# RestSharp RestClient Confusion

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I'm setting up an API call that I know works with the given credentials. I'm new to C# and .NET in general and I've been told to use RestSharp for API calls. What gets passed as an argument to RestClient? I've tried my local server but not sure that's it.

Here is the controller code:

```
    const string endpoint = "https://api.test.hotelbeds.com/hotel-api/1.0/status";

    string signature;

    using (var sha = SHA256.Create())
    {
        long ts = (long)(DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)).TotalMilliseconds / 1000;
        Console.WriteLine("Timestamp: " + ts);
        var computedHash = sha.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(apiKey + sharedSecret + ts));
        signature = BitConverter.ToString(computedHash).Replace("-", "");
    }

    var client = new RestClient("?");
    var request = new RestRequest(endpoint, Method.GET);

    request.AddHeader("X-Signature", signature);
    request.AddHeader("Api-Key", apiKey);            

    var  response = client.Execute(request);
    Debug.WriteLine("this is the response" + response);

    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The endpoint should be passed into the constructor of `RestClient`. The URL segments should be passed into the `RestRequst`.

From the example on http://restsharp.org/

```
var client = new RestClient("http://example.com");
// client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(username, password);

var request = new RestRequest("resource/{id}", Method.POST);
request.AddParameter("name", "value"); // adds to POST or URL querystring based on Method
request.AddUrlSegment("id", "123"); // replaces matching token in request.Resource
```

So in your example, you should declare endpoint as:

```
https://api.test.hotelbeds.com/
```

and pass `hotel-api/1.0/status` into the `RestRequest` constructor.

Comment: Ok, i saw that example, don't know why I over complicated it. Thanks.